# Asio reading stream_file asynchronously fails with coroutines and alternatives

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, coroutine, asio

I am using Boost.Asio 1.78 and I cannot use `file_stream::async_read_some` with any method and make it work in Asio.

For co_await, it throws a `22, Invalid argument` and for any alternative method, it is not being run. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed liburing for file IO from https://github.com/quickemu-project/quickemu

This is the read file coroutine:

```
boost::asio::awaitable<boost::container::vector<std::byte>> read_file_async(
   boost::asio::any_io_executor & exe, 
   const std::filesystem::path & p) { 
   using boost::asio::use_awaitable;
   boost::asio::stream_file file(exe, p.c_str(), 
                                 boost::asio::file_base::read_only | boost::asio::file_base::exclusive);

   if (!file.is_open()) {
     throw std::runtime_error(fmt::format("Could not open {}", p._c_str()));
   }
   constexpr std::size_t block_size = 1024 * 1024 * 2; 
   boost::container::vector<std::byte> buf(block_size, boost::container::default_init); 
   std::size_t curr_pos = 0; 
   std::size_t bytes_read = 1; 
   std::vector<std::byte> v(block_size);
   while (bytes_read > 0) {
       try {
         bytes_read = co_await file.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf.data() + curr_pos,
                                                                        buf.size() - curr_pos),
                                                    use_awaitable);
         curr_pos += bytes_read;
         if (curr_pos == buf.size())
           buf.resize(buf.size() * 2, boost::container::default_init);
       }
       catch (const boost::system::system_error & e) {
         fmt::print("{}\n", e.what());
         throw;
       }
   }
   buf.resize(curr_pos, boost::container::default_init);
   buf.shrink_to_fit();
   co_return std::move(buf);
 }
```

This is the code that calls the reading file coroutine:

```
boost::asio::io_context ctx;
auto the_task =
     [&](std::filesystem::path p) -> boost::asio::awaitable<void> {
       boost::asio::any_io_executor executor = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
       auto file_contents = co_await read_file_async(executor, p);
   };
  for (const auto &file_path : rng)
    boost::asio::co_spawn(ctx, the_task(file_path), boost::asio::detached);
  ctx.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where completion handlers for `file_stream::async_read_some` and `file_stream::async_write_some` were not completing because `epoll` was disabled.

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html) and **set** `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IO_URING` and but **did not** set `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_EPOLL`. Now my completion handlers, complete correctly.